# Material-UI sketch files

Tags: material-ui, sketch-3

Are there any existing PSD or Sketch (preferred option) files for Material-UI components available?

https://material-ui.com/

I can use Sketch build in Material Design Template v2 for mockups but I am not sure if that is an accurate representation of the components for prod design. And that is something that can cause issues later on.

http://www.sketchappsources.com/free-source/1601-material-design-sketch-template-v2.html

Comment: On the official material design site there's everything for Sketch, After Effects, Photoshop and Illustrator: [https://material.io/guidelines/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-components](https://material.io/guidelines/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-components)

Comment: Looks like the url changed, I found it here: https://material.io/archive/guidelines/resources/sticker-sheets-icons.html#sticker-sheets-icons-components

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Material-UI has an official [version for Sketch](https://themes.material-ui.com/themes/sketch-react/), they are an accurate representation of production and kept in sync with the React components.

[image: Material-UI for Sketch]

---

Alternatively,

- Sketch has a [few symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEEAA.png) for Material Design but they cover very few of the components and an outdated version of the specification.
- Material Design has a [Sketch plugin](https://material.io/resources/theme-editor/) but it supports fewer components than Material-UI and doesn't use the same wording/structure as Material-UI that makes it harder to move from design to implementation.